# How do I save difference between 2 timestaps in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to subtract a saved time in a document from the current time and save it in a different field of that document.
I tried $subtract which returns value in milliseconds and I tried to save it in a field with type Number but getting cast error.

Here is what I tried

```
            abc.updateOne({ checklistId: req.query.checklistId }, { timeCompleted: { $subtract: [ new Date(), "$timeCreated" ] } }).then(() => {
              console.log('time updated');
            })
```

Error

CastError: Cast to number failed for value "{ '$subtract': [ 2019-05-14T07:24:24.751Z, '$timeCreated' ] }" at path "timeCompleted"

Comment: Also, how can store the result in Hours

Comment: `$subtract`  is aggregation operator not the update operator.

Comment: Use moment which has good support for date.Check the link below.             https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/